# jQuery preventDefault() is not working after each function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all input from a form using each function. But the Preventdefault not working after each function.

```js
$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e){
    var masterArray = array();
    var stringify = '';
    $(".input-class").each(function(){
        $id = $(this).attr('id');
        $data = $(this).val();
        $myArray = array();
        
        if ($eamount == 0) {
      myArray = {
                scheme_code:$id,
                amount:0
            };
        }else{
      myArray = {
                scheme_code:$id,
                amount:$data
            };
        }
     masterArray.push(myArray);
    });
    stringify = JSON.stringify(investmentArray);
    e.preventDefault();
)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `e.preventDefault()` just after event binding

```
$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  // rest stuff

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use return false .

```js
$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e){
 var masterArray = array();
 var stringify = '';
 $(".investment-amount").each(function(e){
          $id = $(this).attr('id');
          $data = $(this).val();
          $myArray = array();

          if ($eamount == 0) {
            myArray = {
              scheme_code:$id,
              amount:0
            };
          }else{
            myArray = {
              scheme_code:$id,
              amount:$data
            };
          }
          masterArray.push(myArray);
        });

        stringify = JSON.stringify(investmentArray);

   return false;
)};
```

Comment: have a look closely, the `preventDefault` is not inside the each loop, hence, passing `e` inside each loop have no effect

Comment: edited my answer ... let me know is it working or not ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(".investment-amount").each(function(e){
   var masterArray = array();
   var stringify = '';
   $(".investment-amount").each(function(e){
      $id = $(this).attr('id');
      $data = $(this).val();
      $myArray = array();

      if ($eamount == 0) {
        myArray = {
          scheme_code:$id,
          amount:0
        };
      }else{
        myArray = {
          scheme_code:$id,
          amount:$data
        };
      }
      masterArray.push(myArray);
    });

    stringify = JSON.stringify(investmentArray);



 e.preventDefault();
)};
```

Comment: your answer is totally different with what the OP want it and i don't see the point to have double loop that will solve anything that OP mention